# JS doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, popup

I use some JS to make the Cookie advice to users. And it works good on Chrome, IE and Safari. When I test it on Firefox, banner doesn't close when I click on close link. 
Can anybody help me?

This is the JS I use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cookies").addClass("display");
});


$("#close-cookies").click(function(){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#cookies").addClass("close-cookies");
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="cookies">
  <p>blablablabla</p>
  <p><a href="#" id="close-cookies">CLOSE</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the styles for #cookies, #display and #close_cookies?

Comment: The `.click()` function should be inside `ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't initialize the `event` variable

```
$("#close-cookies").click(function(event){
```

and this needs to be inside

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

so the fixed code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cookies").addClass("display");
  $("#close-cookies").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#cookies").addClass("close-cookies");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you zoranc! Just adding event it worked! 
I'm a noob, i need to study much more!

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
$("#close-cookies").click(function(){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#cookies").addClass("close-cookies");
});
```

is out of  $(document).ready(); which means that is executed before the HTML elements are rendered

Comment: Thank you! i just did what Zoranc said. Adding event variable it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the class which is already assigned and then again add a class to ID cookies:

```
$("#close-cookies").click(function(){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#cookies").removeAttr("class").addClass("close-cookies");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! i just did what Zoranc said. Adding event variable it worked in all browsers! thank you anyway!